# How to get the near balance of an account near_sdk_sim?

Tags: nearprotocol

Getting balance of fungible token in near_sdk_sim is

```
let bob = root.create_user("bob".to_string(), to_yocto("1000000"));    
let bob_balance: U128 =
            view!(contract.ft_balance_of(bob.valid_account_id())).unwrap_json();
assert_eq!(bob_balance.0, 5000);
```

But how to get the near balance of account bob?

Answer (score 1):

Get the account info via `account` method ([doc](https://docs.rs/near-sdk-sim/3.2.0/near_sdk_sim/struct.UserAccount.html#method.account)). It returns an `Option<Account>`, `Account` has an amount field.

```
bob.account().unwrap().amount
```